# Deep probe of peer0.org1.example.com:7051 failed: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

i am am getting a warning in the peer logs. Not sure why i am getting this.

`Deep probe of peer0.org1.example.com:7051 failed: context deadline exceeded github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).learnAnchorPeers.func1
 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:249
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery.(*gossipDiscoveryImpl).Connect.func1
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery/discovery_impl.go:152
runtime.goexit
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337`

Could not connect to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 [] [] peer0.org1.example.com:7051 } : context deadline exceeded.

my peer command is as follows.

> docker run --name peer0.org1.example.com -itd -p 7051:7051 -p 7063:7063 --dns-search=. -w /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric --privileged=true --env CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2500s --env CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s --env CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=skynet --env CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=DEBUG --env CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true --env CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true --env CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock --env CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com --env CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG --env CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG --env CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=hostname:7051 --env CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=skynet --env CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP --env CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp --env CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB --env CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=hostname:5964 -v /var/run/:/host/var/run/ -v /export/workspace/hyperledger/docker/channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts -v /export/workspace/hyperledger/docker/crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0 peer node start

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue and below is my observation. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
 1. I stopped the network(docker swarm network) which consists of 2 Orgs and 4 peers.
 2. I didn't remove the previous data(docker named volume).
 3. Before stopping the network, Anchor peers of both the Organization 
     communicating to each other via gossip protocol.
 4. Again, I started the network in below manner:
     ---> first started Org2 peers
     ---> then started Org1 peers. 
   
So here, since Anchor peer of Org2 knows about Anchor peer of Org1 hence as soon
 as Org2 peers are up it started looking for Org1 Anchor peer but all the peers 
of Org1 aren't up yet. So as long as Org1 peers are down, It will continue to 
show this error. 

But once the Org1 peers are up then Org2 Anchor peer able to connect to Org1 
Anchor peer and hence network started working fine.
```

**NOTE: In my case this happened only because I didn't remove the `previous data(docker named volume)` before restarting the network.**

Answer (score 0):

Check this file(configtx.yaml)

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It looks your peer container environment variable is misconfigured.
Try to change
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
instead of
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=hostname:7051